# Acceso a datos de grilla interactiva en ORACLE Apex

Tags: javascript, oracle, apex

soy nuevo en el grupo, soy más de desarrollo en PL/SQL que en javaScript ¿Existe una manera de acceder a los datos de una grilla interactiva en ORACLE Apex usando JavaScript? Encontré algunas referencias pero no me queda claro como funcionan.

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio y lee [ask]: ¿Cuáles han sido las referencias que encontraste? Haz clic en [edit] para proveer más detalles.

Comment: ¿Realmente necesitas acceder a los datos de la grilla usando JavaScript? Porque podrías acceder a dichos datos con PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Si prefieres escribir código PL/SQL, puedes hacer referencia a las columnas de la Grilla Interactiva usando dos puntos en validaciones o procesos, por ejemplo:

```
BEGIN
:columna_ig1 := 10;
END;
```

Si lo que requieres es extender la funcionalidad de la Grilla, puedes revisar este [artículo](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/extending-interaction-to-interactive-grids), donde se muestra el código completo para acceder a los datos de la grilla. Puedes usar:

- model.setValue
- model.getValue

Comment: Hola que tal... efectivamente lo que busco es extender la funcionalidad dela grilla, buscaba algo basado en PL/SQL pero veo que esto no sería tan sencillo. Muchas gracias por tu aporte. Voy a revisar el artículo.